# Determine what object is sending the event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript executing, and i am trying to figure out which type of object is sending the signal. The onblur event is occurring when it is not suppose to, So i would like to be able to filter out the onblur event, to when an `[Object HTMLInputElement]` does it. So far i am receiving that from my `sender` variable. What does the `if` statement look like to filter out the responses to only be used when and HTMLInputElement does it.

So far i have been trying `typeof` but it only returns and `Object` which is not specific enough look for only inputs.

Comment: You can check for element's `tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input'`.

Comment: Indeed, checking the `elem.tagName` property is the best, else you'll want `elem instanceof HTMLInputElement` but `HTMLInputElement` doesn't exist <= IE8 I don't think.